# Typhoeus: How to write code in order to send and run a request more times but stop this process on the first successful response?

Tags: ruby

I am using the Typhoeus gem. The [official documentation](https://github.com/dbalatero/typhoeus) refers to Memoization:

> **Memoization**: Hydra memoizes requests within a single run call. You
>   can also disable memoization.

```
hydra = Typhoeus::Hydra.new
2.times do
  r = Typhoeus::Request.new("http://localhost/3000/users/1")
  hydra.queue r
end
hydra.run # this will result in a single request being issued. However, the on_complete handlers of both will be called.
hydra.disable_memoization
2.times do
  r = Typhoeus::Request.new("http://localhost/3000/users/1")
  hydra.queue r
end
hydra.run # this will result in a two requests.
```

How do I write code to send and run a request multiple times but stop on the first successful response? Also, I would like to skip the current request if it has timed-out.

Comment: This looks a lot like a question, but I don't think it is one. Instead of posting what you're doing, maybe you could rough in what you're trying to do and where you're having problems.

Comment: You are right. But, since I am new to Typhoeus, write that code (if it is possible to make what I aim) is hard: this is my problem! ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at Typhoeus's [`times.rb`](https://github.com/dbalatero/typhoeus/blob/master/examples/times.rb) example.

Don't submit multiple requests to a URL to the Hydra queue, only do one per URL.

Inside the `on_complete` block you have access to the response object. The response object has a `timed_out?` method which checks to see if the request timed out. If it did, resubmit your request to Hydra then exit the block, otherwise process the content as normal.